# Some thing like Gmail drag drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I think every one know with gmail attachment uploading with drag drop,

what is the approach to design a thing lyc that ?  .. drag and drop a image to a place and it should be uploaded to the server .. any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u able to use jQuery ?
see live [Demo](http://www.thecssninja.com/demo/drag-drop_upload/v2/)
Maybe this will help you. However, expect to work only on real browsers (so IE is excluded!)

### Update(Better option):

You can drag & drop files from your desktop on this webpage with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Apple Safari.
http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload
Tested with Firefox 6 well works.

Comment: Thanks , but this dose not work for me in Chrome 12.0.733.0 dev

Comment: Seems broken in FF 6.0.2 as well.

Comment: But this plugin not upload image from browser (URL).

Answer (score 3):

Its not exactly HTML5 but [here](http://www.plupload.com) is a jQuery plugin that does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This library provides both drag-and-drop and multi-file select uploads: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Comment: Oops, I added the .git at the end by accident.